# My form code is showing on my website instead of rendering?

Tags: html, forms, flask, web

I've run into a problem where my code inside my form is showing on my webpage instead of rendering - has anyone encountered this problem before? If so - help please!:)

[my form code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEj7x.png)

[my second form code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBtkB.png)

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLIPy.png)

Comment: `Flask is a micro web framework written in Python.` 

You're just running the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the HTML file directly, which will render what is written in it without any template evaluation.

You need to run the server and visit the page from there.

From your structure it seems that your app will run using `run.py`.
Open a terminal in the root folder of directory and run the python file.

```sh
python run.py
```

This will run the Python file and start the server. You can now go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`.

I don't know what is there in `run.py`. Please paste the code (not the images) of `run.py` here.

Here are some links for reference:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/

Comment: This is my run.py file:   from shop import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

Comment: so you need to do the above things mentioned and visit the address mentioned. Your html page will be on the defined route.